# Fake 3D effect in SFML - follow up

Tags: c++, c++11, sfml

Based on my [previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/111485/fake-3d-effect-in-sfml), I have implemented all the recommendations received.

Here is a summary of the improvements:

- Use meaningful names as much as possible.
- Removed multiple declarations in one line.
- Removed the `dynamic_cast`s and applied a new class hierarchy design.
- Added a `Game` class to improve code modularity.

I would like to know whether or not I have implemented the class hierarchy design for `Colors` in a suitable way.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>


namespace
{
    float increase(float start, float increment, float max)
    {
        auto result = start + increment;

        while (result >= max)
            result -= max;

        while (result < 0)
            result += max;

        return result;
    }

    float limit(float value, float min, float max)
    {
        return std::max(min, std::min(value, max));
    }
}

class Polygon : public sf::Drawable, public sf::Transformable, sf::NonCopyable
{
public:
    Polygon() : mVertices(sf::Quads, 4u) {}

    void setVertices(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, float x3, float y3, float x4, float y4, sf::Color color)
    {
        mVertices[0].position = sf::Vector2f(x1, y1);
        mVertices[1].position = sf::Vector2f(x2, y2);
        mVertices[2].position = sf::Vector2f(x3, y3);
        mVertices[3].position = sf::Vector2f(x4, y4);

        mVertices[0].color = mVertices[1].color = mVertices[2].color = mVertices[3].color = color;
    }

private:
    void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const
    {
        states.transform *= getTransform();

        target.draw(mVertices, states);
    }

    sf::VertexArray mVertices;
};

struct Point
{
    struct Screen
    {
        float x{};
        float y{};
        float width{};
    }screen{};

    sf::Vector3f world{};
    sf::Vector3f camera{};

    void project(float cameraX, float cameraY, float cameraZ, float cameraDepth, float width, float height, float roadWidth)
    {
        camera.x = world.x - cameraX;
        camera.y = world.y - cameraY;
        camera.z = world.z - cameraZ;

        auto scale = cameraDepth / camera.z;
        screen.x = width / 2.f + scale * camera.x  * width / 2.f;
        screen.y = height / 2.f - scale * camera.y  * height / 2.f;
        screen.width = scale * roadWidth * width / 2.f;
    }
};

class Colors
{
public:
    Colors() : mSelf(this) {}
    virtual ~Colors() = default;

    virtual sf::Color getRoad() { return{}; }
    virtual sf::Color getGrass() { return{}; }
    virtual sf::Color getRumble() { return{}; }
    virtual sf::Color getLane() { return{}; }

    void setColor(Colors& c) { mSelf = &c; }
    Colors& getColor() const { return *mSelf; }


private:
    Colors* mSelf;
};

class Light : public Colors
{
    sf::Color getRoad() {
        return{ 100, 100, 100 };
    }
    sf::Color getGrass() {
        return{ 16, 170, 16 };
    }
    sf::Color getRumble() {
        return{ 85, 85 , 85 };
    }
    sf::Color getLane() {
        return{ sf::Color::White };
    }
}light;

class Dark : public Colors
{
    sf::Color getRoad() {
        return{ 100, 100, 100 };
    }
    sf::Color getGrass() {
        return{ 0, 154, 0 };
    }
    sf::Color getRumble() {
        return{ 187,187, 187 };
    }
    sf::Color getLane() {
        return{ 100, 100, 100 };
    }
}dark;

class Segment : public sf::Drawable, public sf::Transformable, sf::NonCopyable
{
public:
    Segment()
        : mPoint1()
        , mPoint2()
        , mRumbleSide1()
        , mRumbleSide2()
        , mLanes1()
        , mLanes2()
        , mMainRoad()
        , mLandscape()
        , mColors()
        , mIndex()
    {}

    Point&  getPoint1() { return mPoint1; }
    Point&  getPoint2() { return mPoint2; }

    void setSegmentColors(Colors& it) { mColors.setColor(it); }

    void setIndex(std::size_t i) { mIndex = i; }
    std::size_t getIndex() const { return mIndex; }

    void setGrounds(float width)
    {
        auto lanes = 3u;

        // Landscape
        mLandscape.setSize({ width, mPoint1.screen.y - mPoint2.screen.y });
        mLandscape.setPosition(0, mPoint2.screen.y);
        mLandscape.setFillColor(mColors.getColor().getGrass());

        // Rumble sides
        auto rumbleWidth1 = rumbleWidth(mPoint1.screen.width, lanes);
        auto rumbleWidth2 = rumbleWidth(mPoint2.screen.width, lanes);

        mRumbleSide1.setVertices(mPoint1.screen.x - mPoint1.screen.width - rumbleWidth1, mPoint1.screen.y,
            mPoint1.screen.x - mPoint1.screen.width, mPoint1.screen.y,
            mPoint2.screen.x - mPoint2.screen.width, mPoint2.screen.y,
            mPoint2.screen.x - mPoint2.screen.width - rumbleWidth2, mPoint2.screen.y, mColors.getColor().getRumble());

        mRumbleSide2.setVertices(mPoint1.screen.x + mPoint1.screen.width + rumbleWidth1, mPoint1.screen.y,
            mPoint1.screen.x + mPoint1.screen.width, mPoint1.screen.y,
            mPoint2.screen.x + mPoint2.screen.width, mPoint2.screen.y,
            mPoint2.screen.x + mPoint2.screen.width + rumbleWidth2, mPoint2.screen.y, mColors.getColor().getRumble());

        // Main Road
        mMainRoad.setVertices(mPoint1.screen.x - mPoint1.screen.width, mPoint1.screen.y,
            mPoint1.screen.x + mPoint1.screen.width, mPoint1.screen.y,
            mPoint2.screen.x + mPoint2.screen.width, mPoint2.screen.y,
            mPoint2.screen.x - mPoint2.screen.width, mPoint2.screen.y, mColors.getColor().getRoad());

        // Lanes
        auto laneMarkerWidth1 = laneMarkerWidth(mPoint1.screen.width, lanes);
        auto laneMarkerWidth2 = laneMarkerWidth(mPoint2.screen.width, lanes);
        auto lanew1 = mPoint1.screen.width * 2 / lanes;
        auto lanew2 = mPoint2.screen.width * 2 / lanes;
        auto lanex1 = mPoint1.screen.x - mPoint1.screen.width + lanew1;
        auto lanex2 = mPoint2.screen.x - mPoint2.screen.width + lanew2;

        for (auto lane = 1u; lane < lanes; lanex1 += lanew1 + 1, lanex2 += lanew2 + 1, lane++)
        {
            if (lane == 1)
                mLanes1.setVertices(lanex1 - laneMarkerWidth1 / 2, mPoint1.screen.y,
                    lanex1 + laneMarkerWidth1 / 2, mPoint1.screen.y,
                    lanex2 + laneMarkerWidth2 / 2, mPoint2.screen.y,
                    lanex2 - laneMarkerWidth2 / 2, mPoint2.screen.y, mColors.getColor().getLane());
            else
                mLanes2.setVertices(lanex1 - laneMarkerWidth1 / 2, mPoint1.screen.y,
                    lanex1 + laneMarkerWidth1 / 2, mPoint1.screen.y,
                    lanex2 + laneMarkerWidth2 / 2, mPoint2.screen.y,
                    lanex2 - laneMarkerWidth2 / 2, mPoint2.screen.y, mColors.getColor().getLane());
        }
    }


private:
    float rumbleWidth(float projectedRoadWidth, std::size_t lanes)
    {
        return projectedRoadWidth / std::max(6u, 2 * lanes);
    }

    float laneMarkerWidth(float projectedRoadWidth, std::size_t lanes)
    {
        return projectedRoadWidth / std::max(32u, 8 * lanes);
    }

    void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const
    {
        states.transform *= getTransform();

        target.draw(mLandscape, states);
        target.draw(mRumbleSide1, states);
        target.draw(mRumbleSide2, states);
        target.draw(mMainRoad, states);
        target.draw(mLanes1, states);
        target.draw(mLanes2, states);
    }


private:
    Point mPoint1;
    Point mPoint2;
    Polygon mRumbleSide1;
    Polygon mRumbleSide2;
    Polygon mLanes1;
    Polygon mLanes2;
    Polygon mMainRoad;
    sf::RectangleShape mLandscape;
    Colors mColors;
    std::size_t mIndex;
};

class Game
{
public:
    Game()
        : mWindow(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "test")
        , mSegmentLength(200.f)
        , mPlayerX(0.f)
        , mCameraDepth(1 / std::atan((100 / 2.f)))
        , mCameraHeight(1000.f)
        , mPosition(0.f)
        , mTrackLength(0.f)
        , mSegments()
        , mSpeed(0.f)

    {
        addRoad();
    }

    void run()
    {
        sf::Clock clock;
        auto timeSinceLastUpdate = sf::Time::Zero;

        while (mWindow.isOpen())
        {
            auto elapsedTime = clock.restart();
            timeSinceLastUpdate += elapsedTime;
            while (timeSinceLastUpdate > TimePerFrame)
            {
                timeSinceLastUpdate -= TimePerFrame;

                processEvents();
                update(TimePerFrame);
            }

            render();
        }
    }


private:
    void processEvents()
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (mWindow.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                mWindow.close();
        }
    }

    void update(sf::Time timePerFrame)
    {
        auto dt = timePerFrame.asSeconds();
        auto maxSpeed = mSegmentLength / dt;
        auto accel = maxSpeed / 5.f;
        auto breaking = -maxSpeed;
        auto decel = -accel;
        auto offRoadDecel = -maxSpeed / 2.f;
        auto offRoadLimit = maxSpeed / 4.f;

        const auto&  playerSegment = *mSegments[static_cast<std::size_t>(std::floor(mPosition / mSegmentLength)) % mSegments.size()];
        auto speedPercent = mSpeed / maxSpeed;
        auto dx = dt * speedPercent;

        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left))
            mPlayerX -= dx;

        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right))
            mPlayerX += dx;

        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up))
            mSpeed += accel * dt;
        else
            mSpeed += decel * dt;

        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down))
            mSpeed += breaking * dt;

        if (((mPlayerX < -1.f) || (mPlayerX > 1.f)) && (mSpeed > offRoadLimit))
            mSpeed += offRoadDecel * dt;

        mPlayerX = limit(mPlayerX, -2.f, 2.f);
        mSpeed = limit(mSpeed, 0, maxSpeed);

        mPosition = increase(mPosition, dt * mSpeed, mTrackLength);
    }

    void render()
    {
        auto width = 640.f;
        auto height = 480.f;
        auto roadWidth = 2000.f;
        auto maxy = height;

        const auto& baseSegment = *mSegments[static_cast<std::size_t>(std::floor(mPosition / mSegmentLength)) % mSegments.size()];

        mWindow.clear();

        for (auto n = 0u; n < mSegments.size(); n++)
        {
            auto& segment = *mSegments[(baseSegment.getIndex() + n) % mSegments.size()];

            bool looped = segment.getIndex() < baseSegment.getIndex();

            auto camX = mPlayerX * roadWidth;
            auto camY = mCameraHeight;
            auto camZ = mPosition - (looped ? mTrackLength : 0.f);

            auto& point1 = segment.getPoint1();
            auto& point2 = segment.getPoint2();

            point1.project(camX, camY, camZ, mCameraDepth, width, height, roadWidth);
            point2.project(camX, camY, camZ, mCameraDepth, width, height, roadWidth);

            if ((point1.camera.z <= mCameraDepth) || (point2.screen.y >= maxy))
                continue;

            segment.setGrounds(width);

            mWindow.draw(segment);

            maxy = point2.screen.y;
        }

        mWindow.display();
    }

    void addRoad()
    {
        auto rumbleLength = 3u;
        mSegments.reserve(500);

        for (auto i = 0u; i < 500; ++i)
        {
            auto segment = std::make_unique<Segment>();

            segment->setIndex(i);
            segment->getPoint1().world.z = i * mSegmentLength;
            segment->getPoint2().world.z = (i + 1) * mSegmentLength;

            if (static_cast<std::size_t>(std::floor(i / rumbleLength)) % 2)
                segment->setSegmentColors(light);
            else
                segment->setSegmentColors(dark);

            mSegments.push_back(std::move(segment));
        }

        mTrackLength = mSegments.size() * mSegmentLength;
    }

private:
    sf::RenderWindow mWindow;

    float mSegmentLength;
    float mPlayerX;
    float mCameraDepth;
    float mCameraHeight;

    float mPosition;
    float mTrackLength;

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Segment>> mSegments;

    const static sf::Time TimePerFrame;
    float mSpeed;
};

const sf::Time Game::TimePerFrame = sf::seconds(1 / 60.f);

int main()
{
    try
    {
        Game game;
        game.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << "\nEXCEPTION: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: It was a big improvement from the last one, great job!

Comment: @glampert .. i did what you told me to do. :)

Comment: Hahaha, yes, I'm biased, but I'm sure others will also agree ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I commented, It looks pretty clean overall, so I'll only mention a couple things this time. You might consider waiting a little bit before selecting this, in case other reviewers show up.

- `mSelf` in `Colors` is strange. I didn't quite understand its purpose and what you are trying to achieve with it that can't be accomplished with the `this` pointer. I think you might have done that because of the `getColor/setColor` methods? That's not a very conventional approach. The usual would be for `Segment` to have a `Colors` pointer, then just swap that pointer when you need to `setSegmentColors`.

  ```
  void setSegmentColors(const Colors * c) { mColors = c; }
  ```
- The methods of `Colors` could probably be pure virtual (`= 0;`). I don't suppose you'd need to declare a `Colors` instance by value, one the `mSelf` oddity is fixed.
- When you implement a virtual base class, be sure to annotate the methods in child classes with [`override`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override).
- Also take a look into the [`final` specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final). You can add it to classes that are not meant to be inherited from and to leaf nodes in a class hierarchy.
- All the virtual `get*` methods in `Colors` should be `const`. They are not mutating any member data.
- The globals `light` and `dark`, even though not carrying any member state as of now, should also probably be constants. I'm very picky about `const` because mutable shared state is a major source of bugs. Knowing a thing is `const` greatly reduces the number of places you have to look into if you find an inconsistent state somewhere.
- No need to call the default constructors of all members of `Segment` in its constructor. This is C++11, so if you'd like to emphasise that they are default initialized, you can just use the `{}` syntax on declaration, e.g.: `Point mPoint1{};`. If you do that, you can get rid of `Segment`'s constructor.
- `rumbleWidth()` and `laneMarkerWidth()` could either be joined with the other helpers inside the unnamed namespace or could be declared as `static`, since those are pure functions that are not relying on any member state of `Segment`.